# Bash -gt: unexpected operator

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a `checkSpace.sh` which check the used space on a disk and if is greater than 80 stops a service

```
#!/bin/bash

percent=sudo df /media/usb | tail -n 1 | grep -E [[:digit:]]+% -o | grep -E [1-9]+ -o
if [ $percent -gt 80 ]; then
  sudo service motion stop
fi
echo "used space is"
echo $percent
```

But when i run it with `sudo sh checkSpace.sh` it gives me:

```
1 
checkSpace.sh: 4: [: -gt: unexpected operator 
used space is
```

Comment: Do you really need `sudo` to run the `df` command?  On systems that I have used, `df` runs fine as a normal user.

Comment: A great debugging command is set -x. set +x turns it off. You would see what $percent translates to in the output.

Comment: @John1024 it asks for permission being run on a sudo mounted drive. I don't know if or how can this be changed to not require sudo;

Thanks Robert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the command `sudo df ....`, you need to use *command substitution*.  Thus, replace:

```
percent=sudo df /media/usb | tail -n 1 | grep -E [[:digit:]]+% -o | grep -E [1-9]+ -o
```

With:

```
percent=$(sudo df /media/usb | tail -n 1 | grep -E [[:digit:]]+% -o | grep -E [1-9]+ -o)
```

#### What went wrong

```
percent=sudo df /media/usb | tail -n 1 | grep -E [[:digit:]]+% -o | grep -E [1-9]+ -o
```

In the above command, the shell variable `percent` is temporarily set to the value `sudo` and then the command `df /media/usb` and its output is sent to the `tail` command.  `percent` is given no permanent value and the output of the pipeline is sent to stdout.